# Difference between buffer geometry and geometry

Tags: three.js

I'm new to three JS where I have researched through all the topics such as camera, renderer, scene and geometry. Where coming through the geometry there are geometry and buffer geometry(say conebufferGeometry and coneGeometry).Where the features are same in both. So whats the difference between geometry and buffer geometry. Is that influence anything in performance or something

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is essentially in underlying data structures (how geometry stores and handles vertices, faces etc in memory).

For learning purposes you should not care about it, just use ConeGeometry until you come across performance issues. Then come to the topic again, next time you will be more prepared to get the difference between two.

Please check [BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry)

> An efficient representation of mesh, line, or point geometry. Includes
>   vertex positions, face indices, normals, colors, UVs, and custom
>   attributes within buffers, reducing the cost of passing all this data
>   to the GPU.
>
> To read and edit data in BufferGeometry attributes, see
>   [BufferAttribute documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferAttribute).
>
> **For a less efficient but easier-to-use representation of geometry, see
>   Geometry.**

On another side [Geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Geometry):

> Geometry is a user-friendly alternative to BufferGeometry. Geometries
>   store attributes (vertex positions, faces, colors, etc.) using objects
>   like Vector3 or Color that are easier to read and edit, but less
>   efficient than typed arrays.
>
> **Prefer BufferGeometry for large or serious projects.**

BufferGeometry performance explained here: [why-is-the-geometry-faster-than-buffergeometry](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/why-is-the-geometry-faster-than-buffergeometry/)

Answer (score 3):

Geometry is converted to buffergeometry in the end so if you dont have any performance issues, stick to geometry if its convenient for you.

Here you can see that ConeGeometry calls CylinderGeometry constructor.

```js
CylinderGeometry.call( this, 0, radius, height, radialSegments, heightSegments, openEnded, thetaStart, thetaLength );
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/geometries/ConeGeometry.js

Then CylinderGeometry is created using CylinderBufferGeometry.

```js
this.fromBufferGeometry( new CylinderBufferGeometry( radiusTop, radiusBottom, height, radialSegments, heightSegments, openEnded, thetaStart, thetaLength ) );
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/geometries/CylinderGeometry.js

Answer (score 3):

## From 2021

This is now a moot point, `geometry` was [removed from threejs](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401/26) in **r125**.

`Geometry` is now just an alias for `BufferGeometry`, source [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1e7851d9b6323729e8198c0e6eb06944cf13ba64/src/geometries/BoxGeometry.js#L170).

```js
export { BoxGeometry, BoxGeometry as BoxBufferGeometry };
```